# How to add standart settings from choice field in new custom field based on Choice Type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-field-type

I want to create custom field type based on Choice field in SharePoint 2010. 
My code:
Fldtypes_OpenChoiceField.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">OpenChoice</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Choice</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">OpenChoice</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Choice with open answers</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="AllowBaseTyp eRendering">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnListAuthoringPages">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnDocumentLibraryAuthoringPages">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnSurveyAuthoringPages">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnSurveyCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnColumnTemplateAuthoringPages">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">FieldTypes.SharePoint.OpenChoiceField,$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Field>
    <Field Name=" ">/_controltemplates/Fields_SharePoint/OpenChoiceFieldEditor.ascx</Field>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

OpenChoiceField.cs:

```
namespace FieldTypes.SharePoint
{
    public class OpenChoiceField :  SPFieldChoice
    {
        public OpenChoiceField(SPFieldCollection fields, string fieldName)
            : base(fields, fieldName)
        {
        }

        public OpenChoiceField(SPFieldCollection fields, string typeName, string displayName)
            : base(fields, typeName, displayName)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I create column with custom field type I see in section Additional Column Settings only default settings (description, require, enforce unique, add to default view). But I need all setting such in Choice Field (Type each choice..., Display choices using, Allow Fill-in choices, default value). 
How can I insert these properties in my custom field? 
May be need I add some standart controls to edit control (/_controltemplates/Fields_SharePoint/OpenChoiceFieldEditor.ascx)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good example of a custom field then go to this [blog](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2011/11/07/walkthrough-custom-field-type-for-uploading-and-displaying-images-in-sharepoint-2010-lists/) by Bernado Nguyen-Hoan.

You will have to add the custom properties to your xml like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">ImageUpload</Field>
    ...
    ...
    <PropertySchema>
      <Fields>
        <Field 
            Name="UploadImagesTo"
            DisplayName="UploadImagesTo"
            MaxLength="255"
            DisplaySize="100"
            Type="Text"
            Hidden="TRUE">
          <Default>Images</Default>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </PropertySchema>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

You will also have to override the `Update` method in your `OpenChoiceFieldClass`:

```
public override void Update()
{
  base.SetCustomProperty("UploadImagesTo",
  Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("UploadImagesTo")));

  base.Update();
}
```

The blog post will also show you how to set up your own custom Control and Editor for the field as well.